# Kusto to construct a new table based on values from another table

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

Need help in Kusto to construct a new table based on values from another table:
I have a table like this:

```
month_end_date  value
2023-04-30      0
2023-05-31      1
2023-06-30      0
```

I need to construct dates like this:

```
print date_part=range(todatetime('2023-05-28'), todatetime('2023-07-03), 1d)
| mvexpand date_part
```

and fill out values from my previous table with these new date ranges. meaning if the date is >=2023-06-30 or the latest date, fill out with the value in value column which is 0, and if it is between 2023-06-30 and 2023-05-31, with respected value in 2023-05-31 which is 1, and if less than 2023-05-31, with respected value for 2023-04-30 which is 0.
construction of date_part could be different like just using extend and add dates based on the range specified, whatever helps achieve better result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Below is the KQL query which worked for me:

```
let originalTable = datatable(month_end_date: datetime, value: dynamic)
[
    datetime(2023-04-30), 0,
    datetime(2023-05-31), 1,
    datetime(2023-06-30), 0
];
let dateRange=range x from todatetime('2023-05-28') to todatetime('2023-07-03') step 1d;
let r=originalTable
| join kind=fullouter (
    dateRange
) on $left.month_end_date == $right.x
| extend date1=iff(isnull(month_end_date),x,month_end_date)
|order by date1 asc 
|project-away month_end_date,x
| sort by date1 asc
| extend rn=row_number();
r
| project date1,value
| summarize c = make_list_with_nulls(value)
| extend d = series_fill_forward(c)
| mv-expand d = d 
|project-away c
|extend valuess= toint(d)
| extend new_column = 0
| sort by new_column asc
| extend rn=row_number()
| join kind=inner r on rn
|project-away rn, rn1,value,new_column,d
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

1st part
[image]

2nd part

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/SampleMetrics?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32S3W6jQAyF7%20cpfFGpIA0VSdrd1Va8RNW7aoUmYNpp5yfyDIVUefj1ENqGKCoIhOazj49tDEbwpJ%201U%20ZRbQ1CBa2KfPN3Zr2LLzW6tuYz/JsIRm1RwrsyfTrYO2V1k4snAXx98mxdrjdFeVtsylxCKS/Bu2KzYri6CH/NmeLfvTBsMeEH5Z6xovSGETryFqL/yrv%20VF3/uc4ZXGC/i3LDLETcwao9ClO16F4c4NVrB2/atVXXG%20P7iATZl8fJhMjBO7gy2MWb5YigquCKBV/izchaOEYmU%20Kq0l2X6eBY9GyuuRzl2Yk4eGq58HZ/TAYVGhCHHflXbGKhBrWHZYpM9YKnuMj59kCuIj/UrrdbpCy/F8Rs1jvGy2mnSaW3VpH%20QGj4b7DqDWujQ6wHzfWS/5BNoflJhxwYkDSGutPG1J2nQVGbNSnGvhc47tQc1p73wSZnlUk1hIp3p13M2pMCDoe68aa3jiXKk1ZPwE/9LharnePZUloiuTM35CQ/8zDkt7ps/wMxT%20dDKwMAAA==).

Try to follow to follow above query to get desired result as I have got.